# How can I produce a chart using count as a measure in SlamData?

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

I'm using SlamData to model data stored in MongoDB. Each object looks something like this:

```
{
//... other fields
 rating: 3
//...  other fields
}
```

When I try to build my chart, I select "rating" as the category, but then it seems I have no option to simply count the number of ratings.

I'm looking for a chart with 5 bars (the ratings are 1-5). For each bar, I want to display the number of objects with that rating.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of SlamData when building out a bar chart, you need to provide a field that can be used for the category and a field that can be used for the measure. What I would do is something along the lines of the following:

1. Add a **Query** card with a query similar to the following:

   ```
   select
           count(*) as cnt
       ,   rating
   from
           `/mount/database/collection`
   group by
           rating
   ```

   2. Add a **Setup Chart** card and choose **Bar Chart** with the following information:

      **Category**: rating
      **Measure**: cnt
   3. Add a **Show Chart** card

That should give you what you need.